# c++ sort struct with 3 elements segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, segmentation-fault, stdvector

My full program is [here](http://pastebin.com/Yc6un9AK).
I have a struct like this

```
struct video_cluster {
    boost::filesystem::path vid_path;
    boost::filesystem::path img_path;
    int cluster_num;
};
```

and a sorting method

```
struct by_cluster_num{
    bool operator()(const video_cluster &a,const video_cluster &b) { 
        return a.cluster_num < b.cluster_num;
    }
};
```

First i create a vector to push result in

```
std::vector<video_cluster> result_new;
```

Then i add result into result vector by

```
video_cluster tmp;
tmp.vid_path = vids[j];
tmp.img_path =to;
tmp.cluster_num = clusters[j];
result_new.push_back(tmp);
```

Then sort the result vector

```
 std::sort(result_new.begin(), result_new.end(), by_cluster_num());
```

It caused an **segmentation fault** .
Even when i tried to access to their element by

```
std::cout << result_new.back().img_path<<" "<<result_new.back().vid_path<<" "<<result_new.back().cluster_num<<"\n";
```

Same thing **segmentation fault** ..

But if i try to change my struct into

```
struct video_cluster {
    boost::filesystem::path img_path;
    int cluster_num;
};
```

with only 2 elements , everything is fine . Output result is ok , nothing run wrong.
I just don't get it . **Where did i do wrong ??**
I also tried to change struct inside from  boost::filesystem::path to std::string but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you are not filling up your struct instances with junk?

Comment: What's the stack trace when you get the segmentation fault?

Comment: It only "Segmentation-fault" . I think the problem happened whenever i tried to access struct 's "vid_path" or "img_path"

Comment: Use your favorite debugger to get a stack trace!

Comment: do not think, try it ;) debugger tells you where the segfault happens!